# Dynamic Expression to query a list

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a method that passes a field that belongs to type T, and then an operator like `Contains` or `Equals` or `StartsWith`

I have this code so far:

```
IQueryable<Review> queryable = this.rvCurReviewSet.AsQueryable<Review>();

var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Review), "review");
var propExp = Expression.Property(paramExp, "ProductID");
MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
var val = Expression.Constant(input, typeof(string));
var containsExp = Expression.Call(propExp, method, val);

Console.WriteLine(queryable.Provider.CreateQuery<Review>(containsExp).Count());
```

When I run this I get the error: Additional information: Argument expression is not valid

Basically, I want to see if a field in Review satisfies the criteria. So, for example I would find `Review.ProductID contains "123"` or `Review.ProductID startsWith "123"` and so on.

Comment: Is there a reason you are required to build the expression "by hand" instead of using the standard LINQ API?  Something like `myProducts.Where(p => p.ProductID.Contains("123"));`

Comment: @AGB I think OP wants to make a simple parser/evaluator and the operator would correspond to a method.

Comment: @AGB 

Yes this is it. I have a DropDownList that has Contains, StartsWith, Equals etc and I wanted the user to be able to choose from the list and it would create an expression based off of that. I just used Contains in this example for simplicity.

Comment: Ok, got it.  What is the type of `rvCurReviewSet`? Is it an instance of `List<Review>`?

Comment: It's a `BindingList<Review>` that I cast to `List<Review>` - however @Rob below gave me the correct solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were nearly there - but you need to pass it a lambda expression..

```
var lam = Expression.Lambda<Func<Review, bool>>(containsExp, paramExp);
Console.WriteLine(queryable.Provider.CreateQuery<Review>(lam).Count());
```

What you had was a body expression, which operated on `review`, but didn't specify *where* the value for `review` comes from.